# Как фоново запустить python3

Tags: python, nginx, сервер, http

Сейчас у я запускаю Python командой - `python3 -m http.server --cgi 5000`  без nginx, работает как отдельный сервер. Нужно сделать так, чтобы сервер был постоянно запущен через nginx и был доступен по http

файловая структура -

```
[
 cgi-bin:[
          script.py
         ],

 index.html,

 file:[
       img.jpg
      ]
]
```

Comment: Как понимать сервер запущенный через nginx? Он может принимать запросы от nginx насколько я понимаю и запущенным через консоль. Вопрос весьма размытый.

Comment: Нужно сделать так, чтобы nginx направлял http запрос, а сервер Python постоянно слушал эти запросы.

Comment: это надо nginx настраивать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаете proxy с помощью nginx (далее инструкция для Ubuntu, для других версий Linux/MacOS все то же самое, но пути конфигурационных файлов могут отличаться).

Для этого для нужного вам домена отредактируйте nginx файл конфигурации /etc/nginx/sites-available/ваш_домен.com .

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ваш_домен.com;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

ваш_домен.com поменяйте на ваше название домена (домен по умолчанию localhost).

Если домен еще не сконфигурирован, затем выполните команду:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ваш_домен.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Или для домена по умолчанию отредактируйте файл /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

5000 это порт вашего Python сервера. Вместо входящего 80 порта вы можете использовать любой другой порт (не забудьте открыть его в файерволе).

Далее проверьте файл конфигурации на ошибки командой:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Перезапустите nginx:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

После того как вы запустите ваш Python сервер, он станет доступным по порту 80 (или любому другому по вашему выбору).

---

Для того чтобы ваш Python сервер был запущен все время, я рекомендую использовать прекрасный [process manager pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/), он поддерживает и Python.

Установка:

```
npm install pm2@latest -g
```

Автозапуск:

```
pm2 startup
```

Запуск Python сервера:

```
pm2 start http-server -p 5000
```

Полезные команды:

```
pm2 list - список всех запущенных процессов (серверов)
pm2 stop 0
pm2 restart 0
pm2 logs - логи
pm2 logs 0 - логи конкретного процесса
pm2 flush - очистить логи
```

Где 0 - номер процесса в списке

Comment: А не `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;`? Со `/` в конце...

Comment: @SergeyNudnov на моем сервере стоит без / в конце, и все работает. В официальной документации nginx есть примеры и с / и без.

Comment: Была с этим слэшем какая-то засада - точно помню. Но вот какая - увы. Лет 10 назад это было... :)